# Ruby on Rails - Update graphic with dropdown choice

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, json

I need to use the year selected by the user in the dropdown menu to update my graphic.

How can I send the information to the controller to do that ?

Here's how I implemented the dropdown :

```
<%= label_tag(:initial_date, "Ano de início") %>
  <% sanjana = [1988, 1991, 1992, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015]  %>
  <%= select_tag(:year, options_for_select(sanjana, :selected => params[:year]), class: 'form-control') %>
```

And that's what I do in the controller :

```
def total_by_state
    @results = []
    @@states_list.each do |s|
      state = State.find_by_abbreviation("#{s}")
      sanctions_by_state = Sanction.where(state_id: state[:id])
      year_selection = []
      #params[:year] = 2010
      sanctions_by_state.each do |s|
        if(s.initial_date.year == params[:year]) 
          year_selection << s
        end
      end
    @results << (year_selection.count)
    end
    @results
  end
```

Comment: what is wrong with using params[:year]

Comment: It don't reload the page, and the information is not received.